# Decoding multi-value JSON

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to create a game API thing that requires this decoded, but I'm not sure how (this is just for a certain user, so the values wont be the same)

```
[
    {
        "Id": 382779,
        "Name": "DarkAge Ninjas"
    },
    {
        "Id": 377291,
        "Name": "Emerald Knights of the Seventh Sanctum"
    },
    {
        "Id": 271454,
        "Name": "Knights of RedCliff"
    },
    {
        "Id": 288278,
        "Name": "Knights of the Splintered Skies "
    },
    {
        "Id": 375307,
        "Name": "Korblox's Empire"
    },
    {
        "Id": 387867,
        "Name": "Ne'Kotikoz"
    },
    {
        "Id": 696519,
        "Name": "Orinthians"
    },
    {
        "Id": 27770,
        "Name": "Retexture Artists Official Channel"
    },
    {
        "Id": 585932,
        "Name": "Retexturing Apprentices "
    },
    {
        "Id": 7,
        "Name": "Roblox"
    },
    {
        "Id": 679727,
        "Name": "ROBLOX Community Staff and Forum Users"
    },
    {
        "Id": 127081,
        "Name": "Roblox Wiki"
    }
]
```

How can I decode this in PHP so It has a list like

`DarkAge Ninjas
Emerald Knights of the Seventh Sanctum
Knights of RedCliff`

etc, and have the Id decoded separately so I can make a clickable link out of it :/

Comment: in which programming language?

Comment: [Read the manual: `json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need `json_decode` to turn json into php array

```
$api_json = '[
    { "Id": 382779, "Name": "DarkAge Ninjas" }, 
    { "Id": 377291, "Name": "Emerald Knights of the Seventh anctum" }
    ...
]';

$api_data = json_decode($api_json, true);

//Now you can loop over the array and print the `Name`
foreach($api_data as $d) {
   echo $d['Name'];
}
```

above code will output

```
DarkAge Ninjas 
Emerald Knights of the Seventh Sanctum 
Knights of RedCliff
...
```

To make link with ids just add this in above loop

```
echo '<a href="'. $d['Id'].'">'. $d['Name'].'</a>';
```

as Ed Cottrell suggested, Read the manual: [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to know more